# OO programming about state

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis

This is my professor's assignment for oo programming. But I found that the marital status can be an variable in the Person class, how can I achieve this with two classes?

Assume people can have marital status: single, married, widow, divorced. Create a state OODP (i.e., Java, JavaScript, C++, Python, or Ruby) that deal with people's marital status. You will have at least two classes: Person, and Marital State. Make sure the following rules are followed:  single->married  married-> divorced | widow  divorced -> married  widow -> married  create a Client class to test your program. Make sure you test valid and invalid change of marital status.
[The assignment page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQWLH.png)

---

These are my codes:

```
public class AssignmentOOP {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person p1 = new Person("p1");
        Person p2 = new Person("p2");
        Person p3 = new Person("p3");
        p1.PrintMaritalStatus();
        p2.PrintMaritalStatus();
        p3.PrintMaritalStatus();
        p1.GetMarried(p2);
        p1.GetMarried(p3);
        p2.Died();
        p1.GetMarried(p3);
    }
}

class Person {
    String maritalstatus;
    boolean mateIsAlive;
    Person mate;
    String name;

    Person(String name1) {
        maritalstatus = "single";
        mate = null;
        name = name1;
    }

    void GetMarried(Person mate) {
        if(this.maritalstatus.equals("married")|| mate.maritalstatus.equals("married"))
        {
            System.out.println("Marital status error! At least one of you are married");
            return;
        } else {
            this.maritalstatus = "married";
            this.mate = mate;
            mate.maritalstatus = "married";
            mate.mate = this;
            System.out.println("Congratulations!!! " + this.name + " and " + mate.name + " are married!");
        }
    }

    void GetDivorced(Person mate) {
        if(this.maritalstatus.equals("married") && this.mate == mate) {
            maritalstatus = "divorced";
            System.out.println(this.name+" and "+mate.name+" are getting divorced.");
        }else if(this.maritalstatus.equals("single")) {
            System.out.println("You are not married and you cannot get divorced before getting married");
        }else if(maritalstatus.equals("widow")) {
            System.out.println("Your marital status is widow, you cannot get divorced.");
        }
    }

    void Died() {
        this.maritalstatus = "dead";
        this.mate.maritalstatus = "widow";
        System.out.println("Sorry for your loss, " + this.mate.name + " marital status is widow.");
    }

    void PrintMaritalStatus() {
        System.out.println(this.name + " marital status is " + this.maritalstatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming rules. method names should be build around verbs, and they go camelCase(). Only class names start UpperCase in java.

Comment: Did your professor say that you you have to use only 2 classes or could you use even more than 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Before copy and past..

This solution is maybe not what your professor want. There are multiple other solutions that could be used in this scenario.

In the following solution **I assume that you can only use 2 classes!**

## Possible Solution

Your `Person` should have a field of type `MaritalState`. This `MaritalState` tracks the state of a `Person` so it don't have to do it by its own.

The following is just *quick and dirty* and is to show you the idea behind an aggregation.

## Person

The `Person` now delegates all the logic that depends on the `MaritalState` to `MatrialState`

```
public class Person {

  MaritalState maritalState;
  Person mate;
  String name;

  Person(String name1) {
    maritalState = new MaritalState();
    mate = null;
    name = name1;
  }

  void GetMarried(Person mate) {
    maritalState.marry(this, mate);
  }

  void GetDivorced(Person mate) {
    maritalState.divorce(this, mate);
  }

  void Died() {
    maritalState.die(this);
  }

  void PrintMaritalStatus() {
    System.out.println(this.name + " maritalState status is " + this.maritalState.get());
  }

  public boolean isMarried() {
    return maritalState.isMarried(maritalState);
  }

  public boolean isSingle() {
    return maritalState.isSingle(maritalState);
  }

  public boolean isWidow() {
    return maritalState.isWidow(maritalState);
  }
}
```

## MaritalState

The logic which was in `Person` is now in `Martiral` state. I extend some functionality like `isSingle()` to make the code more readable.

```
public class MaritalState {

  private static final String MARRIED = "married";
  private static final String SINGLE = "single";
  private static final String WIDOW = "widow";

  private String state;

  private MaritalState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  public MaritalState() {
    this.state = "single";
  }

  void marry(Person person, Person mate) {
    if (person.isMarried() || mate.isMarried()) {
      System.out.println("MaritalState status error! At least one of you are married");
    } else {
      person.maritalState = new MaritalState(MARRIED);
      person.mate = mate;
      mate.maritalState = new MaritalState(MARRIED);
      mate.mate = person;
      System.out.println("Congratulations!!! " + person.name + " and " + mate.name + " are married!");
    }
  }

  void divorce(Person person, Person mate) {
    if (person.isMarried() && person.mate == mate) {
      person.maritalState = new MaritalState("divorced");
      System.out.println(person.name + " and " + mate.name + " are getting divorced.");
    } else if (person.isSingle()) {
      System.out.println("You are not married and you cannot get divorced before getting married");
    } else if (person.isWidow()) {
      System.out.println("Your maritalState status is widow, you cannot get divorced.");
    }
  }

  void die(Person person) {
    person.maritalState = new MaritalState("dead");
    person.mate.maritalState = new MaritalState("widow");
    System.out.println("Sorry for your loss, " + person.mate.name + " maritalState status is widow.");
  }

  public boolean isMarried(MaritalState maritalState) {
    return maritalState.state.equals(MARRIED);
  }

  public boolean isSingle(MaritalState maritalState) {
    return maritalState.state.equals(SINGLE);
  }

  public boolean isWidow(MaritalState maritalState) {
    return maritalState.state.equals(WIDOW);
  }

  public String get() {
    return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
String maritalstatus;
```

That is probably **not** what your professor wants. The point of that marital status is: there is only a fixed set of values.

The proper way to express that is to use an [enum](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) in java, like:

```
public enum MaritalStatus { SINGLE, MARRIED, ... }
```

You could then further enhance this by creating a **state machine**, that implements the rules, such as: when you are SINGLE, and `doMarry()`, your new status should be MARRIED afterwards.

Comment: When the professor told the student to use a language such as Javascript or Ruby, the professor would, in my opinion, want a different solution than an `enum`

Comment: @Roman The question is tagged Java, that was good enough for me to give a java focused answer ;-)